# Teleport Point: Switch to new scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have used the following site to set up the teleportation in my game: https://unity3d.college/2017/05/16/steamvr-locomotion-teleportation-movement/.

As seen from the image, i have inputted 'Location3' as the new scene i would like to teleport to in the build settings. However, when i run the .exe file, i am not able to teleport to a 'Location3' even though I am able to teleport to the other teleport points to a new location in the current scene.
[image: TeleportPoint]

The console logs the "TeleportPoint: Hook up your level loading logic to switch to new scene: Location3".

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve seems to be a scene change (?)
This can be done using

```
Application.LoadLevel("Location3");
```

When you change to this scene you might want to manipulate the position of whatever it is that you want to teleport. This could be achieved by using a static class that does something depending on what scene you are changing too.

Comment: Beware that Application.LoadLevel() is obsolete and shouldn't be used anymore

Comment: Ah, I did not know this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to use Application.LoadLevel(), because that function is **obsolete** and won't be supported in future Unity releases.

You can use:

```
SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("NameOfScene");
```

In order not to keep your Teleportation script from being destroyed you can add the following script to your Teleportation Component.

```
[Serializable]
public class KeepOnSceneChange : MonoBehaviour {
    public void Awake() {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Using this Component your object won't be destroyed when a new scene is loaded and therefor can be used to teleport.